# Rails in Action - Privatizing Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Admin logged in and created a ticket related to project then uploaded an attachment correctly with no errors then when i try to download it it goes to the false condition , when i replaced `can?` with `cannot?` he was able to download the asset , so what is needed to make admin able to download it without changing the current controller show action ?

Note: the false condition it should happen if the user do not have a permission to see assets , but i don't how how this could happen to the admin also cant find it in the book. Does anyone go through this before ?

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def show
        asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
        if  can?(:view, asset.ticket.project)
            send_file asset.asset.path, :filename => asset.asset_file_name,
                                        :content_type => asset.asset_content_type
        else
            flash[:alert] = "The asset you were looking for could not be found."
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end
```

Ability.rb

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        user.permissions.each do |permission|
            can permission.action.to_sym, permission.thing_type.constantize do |thing|
                thing.nil? || permission.thing_id.nil? || permission.thing_id == thing.id
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you show your ability.rb file, please?

Comment: What does user.permissions equal to? For example, do they include 'view' action?

Comment: you can check the [offical repo](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/chapter_9/app/models/ability.rb) of the book , user.permissions because there is a model called permissions , and all what admin should do of what i have done is working except for this